# What's the difference between mountall and mount -a? (Ubuntu, perhaps others)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, mount, fsck

The [mountall man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/mountall.8.html) says "this is a temporary tool until init(8) itself" can do it, basically. Why not just use mount -a? Is there a difference between the two, and if so, which should I use for what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/mountall.8.html), the ubuntu version of mountall does the following :

- reads  fstab(5)
- calls fsck(8)
- calls mount(8)
- and calls swapon(8)

Canonical does not provide much information on the reason why they had to build a
"temporary  tool".

According to mount manual, mount -a "[...] causes all filesystems mentioned in fstab to  be  mounted[...]".

Anyway, I advise you to use mount -a as it works on most unices.

Comment: Seems you are saying you don't see the difference either, right?

Comment: Not at all. For example, I can't see where mount -a would launch fsck (just quickly checked source code and man page) and mountall is described as temporary.